# Why MATLAB is only plotting maximum three functions

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot multiple Fourier series approximations for the function      `f(x)=(x^2-pi^2)^3`, but for some reason my MATLAB will only plot maximum two of the approximations (along with the original f). How can I get it to plot 4 or more? My code for the series is

```
function [Y]=fourier(X)
N=input('enter the value of N:' )
SN=-16*pi^6/35;
for n=1:N 
SN=SN+96*(-1)^n/n^5*(15/n-pi^2).*cos(n*X);
end
Y=SN;
```

and using

```
plot(X,Y1,'b',X,Y2,'r',X,Y3,'m',X,Y4,'g')
```

(where Yi=fourier(X), X=[-pi:0.01:pi] are the various approximations for different N) isn't working; nor is plotting them one by one.

Many thanks in advance for any help that anyone can offer - as you may have noticed I'm a very amateur programmer!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please understand that "isn't working" is never sufficient information. Do you get an error? If so, what is the error? If there's no error, what happens, and what do you expect? Are you sure that the data aren't just overlapping? Try to change the markers for each plot: `plot(X,Y1,'bs',X,Y2,'ro',X,Y3,'mv',X,Y4,'g>')`. Your function is even in `x`, so I wouldn't be surprised if every other order of the Fourier series was the same (since there isn't a sine component)

Comment: Well there's no error, whenever I attempt to plot a fourth function, the one that has most recently been plotted (with the hold on command in place) then vanishes. When plotted all at once, again only three are plotted. Changing the markers as you've suggested is not solving the problem. I take your point about the rapid convergence of the series, but plotting with N=10 for example, there are still points that are distinct from f, and these points should be becoming fewer with each approximation (in fact, this is exactly what I'm visually trying to show). Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: I've never seen this behaviour you're describing. Could you try to add context to your plotting command, essentially providing us with a [mcve]? (I only suggested to add markers to avoid the possibility that the lines are there, just overlapping.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no problems.

I modified your fourier function to accept input `N`:

```
function Y = fourier(X,N)
SN = -16*pi^6/35;
for n = 1:N
    SN = SN+96*(-1)^n/n^5*(15/n-pi^2).*cos(n*X);
end
Y = SN;
```

Then, I get the 4 lines:

```
X  = (-pi:0.01:pi)';
Y = [fourier(X,1), fourier(X,2), fourier(X,3), fourier(X,4)];
plot(X,Y)
legend 1 2 3 4
set(gca, 'Xlim',[-3.3, -2.3], 'Ylim',[-60,79])
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't really address the original problem...does it? Can you reproduce the disappearing-on-new-plot problem?

Comment: @AndrasDeak It does address the fact that the OP might be creating one of the four to be exactly the same as the other. If he can run this code and get the same result, his problems were coming from manual manipulation

Comment: Well, OP clearly states the new plots *make old ones vanish*, and adding markers also verifies this. Your example is helpful as it is indeed interesting if it solves OP's issue as a work-around, but sooner or later they will want to plot more than 3 things, and they might be back at the same problem.

Comment: @AndrasDeak I do not think there is a "disappearing-on-new-plot problem". The easiest way to verify that is to countertest it. This will narrow down the possibilities.

Comment: Yes, yes, I agree:) I guess what I'm saying is that I wouldn't have added an answer that does not answer the question *per se*, but maybe a community wiki due to the code block and the image. (Don't feel pressured, I'm just explaining my scepticism. We'll see how it works out for our OP:)

Comment: That does seem to have solved it...thank you both very much for your help, really appreciate it - I've just never been taught this stuff!

Comment: @DanBurrows glad to hear it:) I'd still advise you to track down your issue: there shouldn't be a bound of number of plots in a figure, and especially not a small number like 3 or 4.